# CSAPP lab datalab dlc is not working in mac osx Yosemite

Tags: c, macos, unix, binaryfiles

recently I've been trying to read the book csapp which was recommend by one of my friends.Things happen when I try to finish the lab assignment [datalab-handout](http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/public/datalab-handout.tar)(Need to download).

When I try to run this command in MacOSX Yosemite:

```
./dlc bits.c
```

Error message was:

```
-bash: ./dlc: cannot execute binary file
```

p.s. here was output when I execute the command:

```
1tekiMacBook-Air:datalab-handout 1$ uname -a
Darwin 1tekiMacBook-Air.local 14.1.0 Darwin Kernel Version 14.1.0: Mon Dec 22    23:10:38 PST 2014; root:xnu-2782.10.72~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

1tekiMacBook-Air:datalab-handout 1$ file dlc
dlc: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, not stripped
```

Can somebody give me a hand? Thx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Because dlc is a precompiled program which was built on another platform. You cannot just execute it on your Mac, use the suggested OS instead.